# Prevent R from coercing non-numeric strings to "NA" when using "as.numeric"

Tags: r

I want to convert a column of numbers to numeric, but there are certain cells that say "New" and "Gone", which I want to retain as characters.

If I use `as.numeric(df$col1)`, the numbers are converted to numeric, but the words are coerced into "NA" values.

Is there any way that I could convert all the numbers to numeric while preventing this coercion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it with a vector because vectors can only contain a single type.  However, you could do it with a list.

```
Data <- data.frame(col1=c("1","2","New","3","Gone"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
List <- lapply(as.list(Data$col1), type.convert, as.is=TRUE)
```

Comment: +1 for `type.convert` I wish I had known about that function sooner.

Answer (score 1):

A column of a data.frame will always be all of the same type.  So you cannot have the string "New" and the number 5 in the same column.

However, an example to get you on your way:

```
x <- c('New', 1, 'Gone', 2)

ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(x)), x, as.numeric(x))
```

Depending on what you're doing this can be extended to apply to your specific case.

Per Joshua's comment, you can use functions in the `ifelse` statement:

```
ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(x)), sprintf('its a string %s', x), sprintf('its a number %f', as.numeric(x)))
```

However, the usual technique for dealing with this situation is as Joshua outlined in his answer.

Comment: I don't understand... your `ifelse` result is the same as `x`.  What am I missing?

Comment: you are correct sir!  I was trying to illustrate a potential method for getting numerics out of a mixed vector without putting NA's in.  Instead of just using `as.numeric(x)` there would need to be an appropriate function to do whatever processing the OP desired.  Given a more complete question, I'd happily give a better answer.  But this way it leaves the fun exploration part to the OP.